# Q: Can't start up Jupyter Lab on MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Trying to start Jupyter Lab using `jupyter lab` gives the following error:

[AttributeError: 'ExtensionManager' object has no attribute '_extensions'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/og30p.png)

In case this has anything to do with Python, I am using version 3.9.5 installed through Homebrew.

```
> which python3
python3: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3
> python3 --version
Python 3.9.5
```

I installed Jupyter using pip3.

I am able to use `jupyter notebook` and `jupyter console`, however. Only `jupyter lab` results in this error message.

Comment: Usually this solves the problem. `pip install -I jupyterlab --no-cache-die --force-reinstall`

Comment: you may just be needing to upgrade nbclassic.

Answer (score 16):

You can either update nbclassic as krassowski mentioned or disable the extension nbclassic until the bug is fixed.

In my case, updating nbclassic did not work on Apple M1. So, I had to disable it using -

```
jupyter server extension disable nbclassic
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to upgrade nbclassic to the latest version:

```
pip install nbclassic==0.2.8   # in May 2021
pip install nbclassic -U       # or just try this (may require running twice)
```

or if using conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge nbclassic=0.2.8   # in May 2021
conda update nbclassic
```

This is because of changes introduced in jupyter-server release two days ago (2021-05-10), see the discussion in [JupyterLab GitHub repo](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10228).

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue.

There are two solutions for this problem you can try anyone which works for you.

##### Solution 1

Disable the nbclassic

```
jupyter server extension disable nbclassic
```

##### Solution 2

or downgrade jupyter_server

```
# if you have installed jupyter with using pip
pip install -U "nbclassic>=0.2.8"

# if you have got jupyter by anaconda
conda install "nbclassic>=0.2.8"
```

Personally, the first solution worked for me.